# At what percip probability should i display rain? (Dark sky API)

Tags: javascript

When coding a weather app with the darksky api, at what percipprobability should i really show "rain" in my app. I compared the data with a radar from switzerland and got different results. Dark Sky shows a probability of 30% and the radar in another app displays rain at this time.

Should i go with the icons instead?

https://darksky.net/dev/docs

Comment: I think this may be too opinion based.  You may want to consider asking the [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).  They may have good thoughts on the subject.

Comment: No really on topic, but.... it depends whether you want your app to indicate 'its raining now' (evidence from radar, or looking out of the window) or 'it might rain' (from forecast). A probability of 30% is not inconsistent with the fact that it's raining.